# Resize and Rearranging html-css page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How is it possible to rearrange the icons, images and tags in a html-css page which supports all kind of screen size. I want a page which is responsive to all kind of screen sizes. It should be compatible in PC, Iphone , Ipad browsers.

Can it be done using responsive web designing ?

If yes, how can i achieve it.
A piece of code will be great for me to understand the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, responsive design is what you want.

Simply add this to your CSS when you want to change your styles depending on screen size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

It's also important to get used to using `%` instead of `px` for a lot of your widths.  Also, be sure to know the inheritance of child elements, that's important for using `%`.  Getting to know `min-width` and `max-width` in CSS is good too.

Say you have three textboxes displayed horizontally across the screen...

HTML:

```
<div class=textbox >
    This is a textbox
</div>
<div class=textbox >
    This is a textbox
</div>
<div class=textbox >
    This is a textbox
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textbox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 33.3%
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

When the screen gets small enough that you want to display the boxes vertically instead of horizontally, you execute this CSS media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

        .textbox {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use media-query or bootstrap for responsive web designing.

media-query is like following for particular screen size:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
```

You can find lots for material for media-query and bootstrap on internet. 
For media-query. [This](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) is good material to understand.
Also, You can find lots of responsive templates available on internet.